# Override webpack loader config for a specific file

Tags: webpack, overriding, vuejs2, webpack-loader

I set-up my new project with [vue-webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), where I use the [jsoneditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor). The default webpack configuration bundles all image assets in the the *img* directory, but the **jsoneditor** expects its icons in the *css/img* directory.

I discovered the *webpack.base.conf.js* file with the rules-configuration, which is set like:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
    },
},
```

So, changing `utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),` to `utils.assetsPath('css/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),` did the trick, but I would like to apply this rule only to the **jsoneditor-icons.svg** file.

Doing `exclude: [path.join(resolve('node_modules'), './jsoneditor/dist/img')],` stops webpack from putting the **jsoneditor-icons** to the */img* folder, but an **additional rule**

```
{
    test: /.*(jsoneditor-icons.svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        name: utils.assetsPath('css/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
    },
},
```

did not do anything.

Could someone please point me to my mistake? The goal is to keep original webpack configuration and only override the rule for the **jsoneditor-icons.svg** file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be the missing *limit:* property in the options object of my overriden settings.

The working configuration looks like:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: utils.assetsPath('css/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
    },
    include: [path.join(resolve('node_modules'), './jsoneditor/dist/img')],
},
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/, // exclude jsoneditor icons
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
    },
    exclude: [path.join(resolve('node_modules'), './jsoneditor/dist/img')],
},
```